# Visual studio 2013 c++ get assertion failure , but can't see the source code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, assertions

my application getting Assertion failed! but when i press Retry im getting this window
This is the Assertion failed! window 
[image]

when clicking Retry im getting this window :
[image]

i to add JIT enabled all app is compiled in debug mode .

Comment: The MCVE principle also applies to compiler and linker flags! :) So please create an MCVE that reproduces the problem, including all compiler and linker flags.

Comment: what is MCVE principle  ? any way it is big project , i can't any way i can publish it here . but it is really standard VC++ project in debug mode

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. You reduce the problem to something so small that people on Stack Overflow are actually willing to analyse it for you. Ideally, it would be a single, small piece of code that can be copy'n'pasted. However, with actual linker problems, it's fine to post the contents of two or three **small** files if it's really necessary. And of course state all the compiler and linker flags you use to invoke the problem.

Comment: Make sure that all of your dlls are compiled with the version of Visual Studio that you are building your application. This kind of error can occur when you are mixing different versions of visual studio.

Comment: i tracked the problem , it was object which was nullptr and some function try to make somthing with this object , but the question is why it didn't get me to the source code ?

Comment: ***but the question is why it didn't get me to the source code ?*** Because the source code is the Visual Studio runtime. And you don't have the symbols installed for the runtime. You can enable the symbol server for that if you want.

Comment: If you check the checkbox on the bottom picture it will enable the symbol server..

Comment: i want the not the server sources but my source code which hold the problem